# Pi video playback - what the heck is happening?

Tags: camera

Im running a short Python script on my Pi which records a h264 steam from the camera module  and when a button is pressed it replays the last 10 seconds over HDMI using omxPlayer.

On nearly all TVs that I've connected it to, it works absolutely fine HOWEVER on one or two TVs the replay speed is lightning fast!

I can't work out why this is happening.

Any ideas?....

Many thanks
Matt

Comment: It is likely due to resolution differences amongst the the TVs

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Do you know if there are any changes in my script I can make to compensate for this on the TVs that play fast?

Comment: have I solved your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds entirely feasible.  If I can set a different resolution in the code to see if that fixes it then it would prove you right. I'm just not sure how to do that...

Comment: If it is the solution I'd love to put it in as an answer you'd approve to get a few points, please do get back to me

Comment: if you share some code maybe I could help?

Comment: Sure, I'll post it on here in a couple of hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is to do with the fact that the H.264 stream output by the camera isn't a "full" MP4, which several players expect. Several players, without the MP4 wrapper, use a default framerate (for example VLC uses 25) regardless of what the file was recorded at (e.g. if it was in one of the high framerate modes like 60fps, VLC plays the files back in apparent slow motion).

A simple workaround is to wrap the H.264 stream in an MP4 which can be done with the `MP4Box` utility from the `gpac` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gpac
$ raspivid -o foo.h264
$ MP4Box -add foo.h264 foo.mp4
```

You should find the resulting MP4 file plays at the correct framerate on all players.